# Stuck with Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF74F27A526 : Stack Overflow

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am having stack overflow related exception.
To be clear on that, I have no recursive function that can lead to blowing up stack. Although somewhere in my application I am creating a huge array with std::array and I am using class templates.

I thought of doing allocating memory dynamically but that is the last thing I want to do, also in template function which causing me the problem goes like this:

```
//class Template
template <class T, int Point, int End>
class Node;
private:
int Point;
int End;
std::array <T, Point*End>;
public:
// Rest of the stuff!
//Operator defined in class
//End of Node object1 is equal to Point of Node object2 always so;

template <int entry>
Node<T,Point,entry> operator* (const Node<T,End,entry> &source)
{
  Node<T,Point,entry> temporary_node(0.);

//for_loop to multiply each element store in std::array

return temporary_node;
}
```

It is important to mention that my array size is somewhere around 10000000.

1. What is the solution if I don't want to use dynamic memory allocation:

   - Let's say if I do, then how can I allocate memory dynamically for temporary node in * operator defined above, as it takes up memory for vector when I do this:

     Node  temporary_node;
2. I am on Windows and I also don't want to increase stack size manually as going over 1MB manually will solve the problem but It will be risky and maybe buggy.

Thank you in advance.

## Edit

I just checked it on Linux and its working perfectly fine over there. Maybe because I thought as stack size for linux is around 8MB considering Virtual also. But ugh! This will make the application less cross platform friendly if I don't consider making it work for windows stack default range.

Comment: If you're throwing a stack overflow exception, you're blowing the stack.  End of.  Ergo, don't blow the stack.  (Someone with better template experience will have to tell you how you're blowing the stack.)

Comment: Anything which I didn't mention? But thank you and don't say " Blowing up ", it hurts my feelings.

Comment: @Shamraiz *//for_loop to multiply each element store in std::array* -- This is a big reason why you should write your templated functions using iterators, not with concrete container types.  If you had done that, the user would simply pass to you the start and end iterator, and it wouldn't matter if the container was a `std::array`, `std::vector`, or just a plain array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That sounds like decent and logical. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot create such large objects on the stack, you must create them on the heap instead.

```
template <int entry>
std::unique_ptr<Node<T,Point,entry>> operator* (const Node<T,End,entry> &source)
{
  auto temporary_node = std::make_unique<Node<T,Point,entry>>(0.);

  //for_loop to multiply each element store in std::array

  return temporary_node;
}
```